# Passing return url form the form

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am trying to pass the value of the return url from the view with the form element to its action method inside of the respective controller. In the action method, I am doing the server side validation check with ModelState.IsValid and everytime the return url is invalid. I don't get what is the problem.

This is my form element:

```
<form asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Login" asp-route-returnurl="@ViewData["ReturnUrl"]" method="post" role="form">
    <h4>Use a local account to log in.</h4>
    <hr />
    <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Email" class="col-md-2"></label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input asp-for="Email" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Email" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Password" class="col-md-2"></label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input asp-for="Password" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Password" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="custom-checkbox">
                <label asp-for="RememberMe">
                    <input asp-for="RememberMe" />
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.RememberMe)
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success form-control">Log in</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <p>
        <a asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Register">Register as a new user?</a>
    </p>
    <p>
        <a asp-controller="Account" asp-action="ForgotPassword">Forgot your password?</a>
    </p>
</form>
```

And this is the action method:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnurl = null)
{
    ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnurl;
    returnurl = returnurl ?? Url.Content("~/");

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, isPersistent: model.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: true);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            return LocalRedirect(returnurl);
        }
        else if (result.IsLockedOut)
        {
            return View("Lockout");
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
            return View(model);
        }
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

I expect to get the reason why the returnurl parameters does not get anything from the form in the view

Answer (score 1):

> I am doing the server side validation check with ModelState.IsValid
> and everytime the return url is invalid. I don't get what is the
> problem.

Well, based on your scenario description and shared code snippet I have treid to reproduce your issue. Regarding your invalid URL one question comes to mind is, what URL you are getting?

Here is another additional use case we should pointed to.

First of all, as you are using [LocalRedirect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.results.localredirect?view=aspnetcore-7.0) which enfore to your URL to be local any URL other than base or local URL would be treated as invalid URL. Because,returnUrl usually populated automatically when you try to access an authorized resource but are not authenticated or authorized.

When you attempt an unauthorized access, the security middleware redirects you to the login page with the returnUrl set but when non local URL founded then LocalRedirect throws exception. You can see below:

[image]

> I expect to get the reason why the returnurl parameters does not get
> anything from the form in the view

As explined, earlier it usually populates automatically with the base local URL when you would hit login page. However, you can pass manually and then can check the local URL. So if you want to filter them, then in order to overcome the exception you can include following condition within your login controller while checking user login here `result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync()`

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnurl = null)
        {
            ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnurl;
            returnurl = returnurl ?? Url.Content("~/");
    
            var checkIfLocaURL = Url.IsLocalUrl(returnurl);
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
    
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnurl) && Url.IsLocalUrl(returnurl))
                {
                    return LocalRedirect(returnurl);
    
                }
                else
                {
                    return Redirect(returnurl);
                }
    
            }
    
            return View("Index");
        }
    }
```

Output:

[image]

**Note:** When it would load login inedex by default it would populate with `/` base path. Please [refer to this official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-8.0#using-a-named-route) if you want to study more. For [redirectLocal check this.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.results.localredirect?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

Comment: Btw how nothing related to the question. How do you create gif ?